# How many cities were destroyed during Independence Day?

Tags: independence-day

From the initial coordinated attack to the destruction of the mother ship, how many cities were destroyed ( in the space of three days)?

Comment: Ah yes. In the scene where the aliens move all their pieces into position, then Checkmate! Except that that's **not how chess is played**.

Comment: I like this question but I suspect the answer is unknowable. Certainly we **see** some cities destroyed but whether the others are is not shown. A safe **assumption** would be all those shown as having a shiphovering over them...but is that an answer?

Comment: I was hoping someone would figure out a timetable of movement and extrapolate the maximum number. They mention other targets being hit after the fact. Also the one they nuke is just sitting over the ruined city for like 12 hours doing nothing after it wiped out the city.

Comment: I found this but how canon it actually is...? - https://www.reddit.com/r/ID4/comments/3wq1hz/complete_list_of_destroyed_cities/

Comment: Hobbiton. Definitely Hobbiton. So, at least one unless of course you believe Peter Jackson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Quick google search told me (or [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ID4/comments/3wq1hz/complete_list_of_destroyed_cities/) told me)

[image: independence day]

36 rows, 3 columns of cities destroyed multiplied is 144

So 108 cities, if I'm not wrong.

Then again, I haven't watched *Independence Day...*

<sub>Disclaimer: I found the image after Paulie_D posted, but by Google search.</sub>

Comment: Isnt the fourth column the places they killed the ships?

Comment: Wow, I'd forgotten that Hong Kong was still governed by the UK at that point.

Comment: I really don't think the movie had this amount of detailed information(?) Where does this come from - I would question the source.

Comment: https://tldrmoviereviews.com/2023/05/23/mapping-the-war-of-1996-independence-day-map-it/ this answer seems to be based on the viral website warof1996.com that was published to promote *Resurgence*

Comment: The reports of my demise are greatly exaggerated. Not a single location in Sweden was hit.